# linked list replacing and deleting

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I want to delete node from linked list given only the node to delete.
Here is the function:

```
function deleteNode(node) {
  if (!node.next)throw new Error()
  node.value = node.next.value
  node.next=node.next.next
}
```

My question is why can't I just do this?  I know it doesn't work, but why?

```
function deleteNode(node) {
  if (!node.next)throw new Error()
  node = node.next
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a chain of 3 nodes previous -> current (to delete) -> next.

The `node` in the function is reference to the node object you want to delete. Another reference to the actual node, is the reference from the previous node. To delete a node, you need to remove the reference from the previous node to it.

Reassigning the `node` to `node.next` would only replace the reference stored in the temporary `node` parameter, but won't change the previous or the current node.

The code in this case "deletes" a node by replacing it's content with the content of the next node. Since the reference to the next node is removed, the next node would be actually be deleted from the list (and garbage collected if no other reference). However, the value would remain. This is not an actual delete of the current node (the original object is still there).

If you want to delete the actual node object, and not replace it's content, you need to traverse the linked list. When you get to the previous node (a node with a `next` property pointing to node you wish to delete), change its `next` property to the deleted node `next` property.

Comment: you said that i would only be replacing the reference stored in the temporary node, but how is the node temporary?  Furthermore, if it is temporary, then wouldn't changing its value and next also be temporary?

Comment: It's not a temporary node, it's a temporary variable named `node`, that has a reference to an object. When you replace the what the `node` variable contains, you don't change the actual object. Setting `node = 5` doesn't transform the actual node to 5.